# Sticky не работает на мобильные устройства

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нашел [такой плагин](http://vizr.ru/page/jquery-sticky-plugin) залипания при прокрутке, проблема в том что залипания не работает под мобильные устройства вот [demo](http://vizr.ru/uploads/_pages/89/demo.html) как сделать так что бы при прокрутке залипания заработало, `position: sticky;` тоже не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогло вот этот плагин: http://bureau.ru/bb/soviet/20130620/stickyeah.js

Добавим в нужный блок `stickyeah` например:

```
<div class="stickyeah">
  <h2>Всё</h2>
  <p>Что угодно.</p>
</div>
```

все отлично работает.

Answer (score 2):

Пропишите в плагине параметру `screenlimit` свойство `false`. По умолчанию оно равно `true` и отключает работу плагина на разрешениях меньше 1024 пикселя.

Comment: Нет, не помогло.

Comment: @newProgrammer Вот так `screenlimit: false,` вставили? Ошибку какую-нибудь выдает?

Comment: Да поставил, ни ошибки ни работоспособности.